# Contacts List Read Permission Error in Android

Tags: android

As you can tell I am a newbie to Android :) and struggling with retrieving contacts list. I did add android.permission.READ_CONTACTS in AndroidManifest.xml but still it is not working. I am running it on Windows 10, in case if that makes any difference. Thanks in advance.

```
09-07 17:27:15.819    5272-5272/? I/art﹕ Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
09-07 17:27:15.819    5272-5272/? I/art﹕ Late-enabling JIT
09-07 17:27:15.821    5272-5272/? I/art﹕ JIT created with code_cache_capacity=2MB compile_threshold=1000
09-07 17:27:15.871    5272-5272/com.sr.phonecontactslist W/System﹕ ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.sr.phonecontactslist-1/lib/x86
09-07 17:27:15.879    5272-5272/com.sr.phonecontactslist D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
09-07 17:27:15.879    5272-5272/com.sr.phonecontactslist E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.sr.phonecontactslist, PID: 5272
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sr.phonecontactslist/com.sr.phonecontactslist.MainActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2 from ProcessRecord{15540fd 5272:com.sr.phonecontactslist/u0a59} (pid=5272, uid=10059) requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS or android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2 from ProcessRecord{15540fd 5272:com.sr.phonecontactslist/u0a59} (pid=5272, uid=10059) requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS or android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS
            at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1599)
            at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1552)
            at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.getContentProvider(ActivityManagerNative.java:3550)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:4778)
            at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContextImpl.java:2018)
            at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:1468)
            at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:475)
            at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:434)
            at com.sr.phonecontactslist.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Which Android version do you use?

Comment: If you are running on Android 6.0, and your `targetSdkVersion` is 23 or higher, then you need to integrate the runtime permission system. I have a blog post that outlines the major scenarios of why you request a permission and you do not seem to get it: https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/08/31/hey-where-did-my-permission-go.html

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was indeed the case, I was using 23. I have switched back to 22 and it fixed the issue. Thanks!